# No estoy pudiendo mantener el valor en una variable global a mi aplicación y no entiendo el por qué

Tags: javascript, funciones, variables, eventos, function

Comunidad, ¡los saludo! agradezco de antemano su ayuda...

No estoy pudiendo mantener el valor en una variable global a mi aplicación y no entiendo el por qué...

Creé una variable 'indice' con la cual llevo el ID de mis productos, la misma la puse en un archivo js en donde almaceno todas las variables globales a mi app y la inicializo en un valor 1. Este archivo lo ubico primero en mi lista de scripts en el HTML como adjunto en la imagen.

Cuando llego a la ejecución de mi archivo main.js en donde cargo unos valores iniciales para mi arreglo de productos (el arreglo de productos lo hago mediante un JSON), voy incrementando para cada producto su id con indice++. Hasta ahí todo bien, me crea mi arreglo de 4 elementos cada uno con su ID de 1 a 4.
El problema viene que al momento de agregar un nuevo producto, para lo cual llamo a la función agregarProducto() ubicada en el archivo manejadorProd.js con un listener desde el main.js no me toma el valor 4 del 'indice' que fue modificado desde el main.js sino que me toma el valor 1 declarado en globales.js.

Cabe destacar que hago todos los incrementos de la variable indice desde el main con indice++ y luego desde la función agregarProducto hago lo mismo.. al hacer el push sobre el arreglo paso como parámetro de id un indice++ y entiendo que ese indice al cual le aplico el ++ ya debería venir con el valor 4 desde el main. Pero al hacer un console.log(indice) al principio de la función agregarProducto() me aparece como valor 1, que es el original de globales.js

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que la función agregarProducto me tome el valor de indice que viene desde el main.js o en su defecto que la función main.js me actualice el valor indice que se encuentra en el archivo globales.js ?

```
let indice = 1;

//Recorre el arreglo de productos creando filas en una tabla HTML con los datos correspondientes
function mostrarProductos() {
    let tabla = document.getElementById('tabla-productos');
    let listaTemp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listadoProductos'));

    for(let p = 0; p < listaTemp.length; p++) {
        let fila = document.createElement('tr'); //Creo una nueva fila a la tabla
        fila.innerHTML = `
                <td>${listaTemp[p].id}</td>
                <td>${listaTemp[p].nombre}</td>
                <td>${listaTemp[p].presentacion}</td>
                <td>$ ${listaTemp[p].precio}</td>
                <td><a href="#" name="delProducto">Eliminar</a></td>
        `; 
        tabla.appendChild(fila); //Agrego la información de un producto en la fila de la tabla
    }
}

function eliminarProducto(elemento){

    if (elemento.name === 'delProducto') {
        elemento.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    };
    
}

function agregarProducto(){
    //Captura de datos de HTML y creación de nuevo objeto Producto
    const nombre = document.getElementById('nombreProducto').value;
    const presentacion = document.getElementById('presentacionProducto').value;
    const producto = document.getElementById('precioProducto').value;
    const nuevoProducto = new Producto(indice++, nombre, presentacion, producto);
    
    //Operaciones JSON sobre el arreglo de Productos
    arregloProductos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listadoProductos'));
    arregloProductos.push(nuevoProducto);
    localStorage.setItem('listadoProductos', JSON.stringify(arregloProductos));

    //Reset de elementos de la página
    document.getElementById('tabla-productos').reset();
    document.getElementById('formulario-nuevo').reset();

    //Listado de Productos con el nuevo producto cargado
    mostrarProductos();
    
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema con usar la variable `indice` para controlar ID de elementos es que no siempre te va a dar el valor adecuado. Por ejemplo, si al cargar la página ya hay elementos en *localStorage*, hay que tomar en cuenta los productos existentes.

Lo más adecuado es leer solo una vez el contenido de *localStorage* y usar el objeto obtenido cada que se requiera. Aparte, es conveniente crear los elementos de la tabla solo una vez y crear solo la fila correspondiente cuando se agregue un nuevo producto.

```
// Define globalmente el arreglo de productos y lee solo una vez
// Al final, agrega || [] por si no existe el elemento en localStorage
const productos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listadoProductos')) || [];
// Tambien define la tabla en contexto global
const tabla = document.getElementById('tabla-productos');

// Crea una función para mostrar solo un producto
function mostrarProducto(indice) {
    let fila = document.createElement('tr'); //Creo una nueva fila a la tabla
    fila.innerHTML = `
        <td>${productos[indice].id}</td>
        <td>${productos[indice].nombre}</td>
        <td>${productos[indice].presentacion}</td>
        <td>$ ${productos[indice].precio}</td>
        <td><a href="#" name="delProducto">Eliminar</a></td>
    `; 
    tabla.appendChild(fila); //Agrego la información de un producto en la fila de la tabla
}

// Si necesitas mostrar todos los productos, recorre el arreglo
// Deberás ejecutar esta función al cargar la página
function mostrarProductos() {
    for(let i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) {
        // Ejecuta la función para agregar cada uno a la tabla
        mostrarProducto(i);
    });
}
// No entiendo cómo funciona esto
function eliminarProducto(elemento){
    if (elemento.name === 'delProducto') {
        elemento.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
    };
    // Deberías eliminar también del arreglo y actualizar en localStorage
}

// Crear solo un producto, agregar a arreglo y guardar en localStorage
function agregarProducto() {
    // Definir ID en 1, suponiendo que el arreglo está vacío
    let id = 1;
    // ¿Hay productos en el arreglo?
    if(productos.length > 0) {
        // Obtener ID de acuerdo al último producto agregado
        id = productos[productos.length - 1].id + 1;
    }
    //Captura de datos de HTML y creación de nuevo objeto Producto
    const nombre = document.getElementById('nombreProducto').value;
    const presentacion = document.getElementById('presentacionProducto').value;
    const producto = document.getElementById('precioProducto').value;
    const nuevoProducto = new Producto(id, nombre, presentacion, producto);
    
    // Insertar nuevo producto en arreglo y actualizar localStorage
    arregloProductos.push(nuevoProducto);
    localStorage.setItem('listadoProductos', JSON.stringify(arregloProductos));

    // Reset solo del formulario
    document.getElementById('formulario-nuevo').reset();

    // Mostrar solo el nuevo producto cargado enviando su posición en el arreglo
    mostrarProducto(productos.length - 1);
};
```